# Keycloak import realm

Tags: java, jdbc, keycloak

I would like to import my realm to database. In keycloak 18 I can call command `kc.sh start --import-realm`
It works great, but only if there is no realm in the external database.
I tried to import the realm with the command:

```
docker run 
    -v ~/realm/:/opt/keycloak/data/import 
    -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=pass 
    -e KC_DB_USERNAME=db 
    -e KC_DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://mydburl/keycloak" 
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2  
    import 
    --file /opt/keycloak/data/import/realm-export.json
    --override true
```

but I get error:

```
No suitable driver found for jjdbc:mysql://mydburl/keycloak
```

Is there any method to import realm before calling `kc.sh start`?
How could I import the database drivers into the container? I tried to add a parameter
`import -Dquarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=mysql`
but it seems to have no effect

Comment: I had that error everytime I did not build the image first. You probably should create your own Docker image and trigger a build of Keycloak first.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
docker run 
    -v ~/realm/:/opt/keycloak/data/import 
    -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=pass 
    -e KC_DB_USERNAME=db 
    -e KC_DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://mydburl/keycloak" 
    quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2  
    start-dev --import-realm
```

It will import all the files within the `/opt/keycloak/data/import` directory

Official docs [KC](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport)